# My computer doesn't boot successfully 90% of the time

Tags: boot

It always gets as far as the Grub menu, but after that, when text appears briefly, the text is sometimes half a screen (which means it's going to boot successfully), and sometimes about two screens (which means it's **not** going to boot). I show this in these videos I took on 4 September 2015:

Bad: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8d6imetl832rqu2/P9040001%20Unsuccessful%20boot.AVI?dl=0

Bad: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7liksig65l42dtx/P9040002%20Unsuccessful%20boot.AVI?dl=0

Good: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0iz4ejq1my5e1rl/P9040003%20Successful%20boot.AVI?dl=0

When it doesn't boot, the only option is to hold the power button down until it goes off, and try again.

I've found that going into a "recovery mode", followed by "Resume normal boot" increases the odds of booting, but it's no guarantee.

I've booted into "boot-repair-disk" several times, and run the repair application, but it only seems to boot once successfully immediately afterwards, which is what I've just had to do after a kernel update this morning. The boot process, therefore, is even longer than the usual 1 minute 20 seconds. This adds 5 or 10 minutes.

If it's any help, here are the reports uploaded automatically from "boot-repair-disk":

http://paste2.org/zfFcFjcz

http://paste.ubuntu.com/13851399/

http://paste.ubuntu.com/14059667/

http://paste.ubuntu.com/14059812/

There's no difference between them as far as I can tell.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a way you could post more of the error message? The kernel log is at /var/log/kern.log you might have to scroll up a ways to find the relevant lines, but then could you add a paste bin link?

Comment: Yes I'm just trying to upload text from kern.log to pastebin.

There's no error message as such.  The two screens of text that I mentioned, that usually appear just after the Grub menu (ie. when the boot is **not** going to work), flash by much too quickly to read.

Comment: I had a scan through kern.log, and didn't spot anything suspicious. At 32MB, it seems to be too big for pastebin.com, so I've uploaded it to Dropbox : https://www.dropbox.com/s/bg3kruuzbkmu3z7/kern.log?dl=0

Comment: Hmm :/.. Well to debug this properly it would help to have the error message.. I saw in the video an error popped on screen for a second.. Could you get a picture of it or somehow get the text?

Comment: I'll try later today. By "error message", do you mean the two screens of text that appear after the dark-pink-coloured Grub menu?

Comment: Yeah, at about 1:17 in your first video... Find the chunk about "kernel panic," that's the most important bit.. Should be at the end of the message

Comment: I'm trying to think of any way to catch that text and I'm struggling. From memory, the camera was on a tripod when I made those videos. I though some "burst" photography might get it, but my camera is not remote control, so it would be impossible to hold it still enough. I don't suppose the text would be in any logs either, seeing as it's an unsuccessful boot. Any ideas? I'm quite keen to resolve this.

Comment: Hmm maybe just take a video so the text is readable? Also maybe try running 'dmesg' from terminal and searching for the kernel panic from there.

Comment: dmesg output: http://pastebin.com/3gfZJ9S1
|
There's no "kernel panic" in there. I'll see if I can get a video.

Comment: Hmm I see... We'll see how the video works out, otherwise I don't know how to help. :/

Comment: OK I just got a video that's still a bit blurry but it's much more legible than the previous ones. I managed to get it perpendicularly to the monitor rather than obliquely. I was using the video function on a happy-snap camera, which is the best that I have. In the event of an unsuccessful boot (90% of the times that I try to boot), there are two screens of text that appear:

Comment: (1) At 31.006 seconds, the same text that appears during a successful boot, immediately followed by; (2) At 31.012 seconds, another screen of text for about 1 second and then a blank screen which remains until I shut it down and try again . This is the hardest type of problem in the world to solve, because it's intermittent. https://www.dropbox.com/s/q19gtzlyglr7x2i/Link%20to%20PC190001.AVI?dl=0

Comment: Hmm.. I spent a good amount of time looking through the logs, and I really can't find anything that appears to be the problem! I'm afraid I can't help you any further. I would suggest trying a disk check and testing your ram for issues, and if that doesn't help just backup and reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: It's well and truly beat me. I've run `fsck` a number of times (from a live CD), run `boot-repair-disk` a few times, and I really don't know what else I can do. For the moment, I'd rather live with the issue than reinstall Ubuntu yet again. It takes quite a lot of time and effort to get everything configured properly. Thanks for your time.

Thinking out loud: The intermittent nature of this issue, and complete lack of any warnings or errors, suggest to me that the issue _might_ be hardware-related. Yikes.

Comment: Hmmm. Now the line (during boot) near the end that says
"[           5.86XXXX]  ata7.00X   state:         [ ERR]    "
(I've used "X" where I don't know the actual character) has caught my eye. I'll try to find out what it means, and I'd appreciate any help to speed up that process.

Answer (score 0):

After all that, it stopped working altogether on 23 January 2016. It turned out that both the Intel W2600CR motherboard, **and** one of the Intel Xeon E5 2680 processors, had failed.

They were both replaced under warranty, which took just under 6 months. As soon as the computer was returned from the other side of the country to me, and as soon as I had the video card also replaced under warranty (it failed during the couple of days getting my computer ticking over properly again), it was functional again.